Why are there so many extra layers in my view hierarchy?
I have a simple app with a login screen. Once you log in, theres a test view that holds "Hello World" Text and nothing else. Its totally functional, but I noticed in the view hierarchy, a ton of screens are being drawn. The buttons also have 5 layers that seem unnecessary. I've researched this but cannot find any examples or anyone else presenting the same issue. Heres what it looks like:

And here are the names and the hierarchy of all the layers:

My question is, what is causing all of the extra layers? And are they an issue? I assume unnecessarily drawing additional layers is going to create performance issues. I've worked in Swift/XCode for two years and have never seen something like this, but I am still relatively new. Here is what my code looks like:
Calling RootScreen from my main app contained within a WindowGroup

//  RootScreen.swift

struct RootScreen: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            if !showSignInView {
                NavigationStack{
                    TestView()
                }
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSignInView) {
                NavigationStack {
                    AuthenticationView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
                }
            }  
    }
}


struct AuthenticationView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()
    @Binding var showSignInView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                //sign in anon code
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign in Anonymously")
            })
            NavigationLink{
                EmailLoginView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            } label: {
                Text("Sign in with email")

            }
        }
    
        .navigationTitle("Sign in")
    }
}



These "extra layers" are all SwiftUI's implementation details. Don't worry about them. Use Instruments to actually measure whether you have a performance problem.

That's just how SwiftUI works, no they're not going to be an issue.
